# How increasing the maximum memory per cpu for a job in Slurm?

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, slurm

When I wanted to submit an array job in Slurm I indicated in configuration script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=4G
#SBATCH --job-name=dat
#SBATCH --array=0-1000%20 
#SBATCH --output=exp-%A_%a.out
#SBATCH --error=exp-%A_%a.err
#SBATCH --partition=32Nodes
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=10
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
```

But after submitting the array job, I realized that the maximum memory of each cpu that can be used by a job is 7500M. How changing the maximum memory per Cpu for a job array in Slurm? I am using Linux terminal.

Comment: If you want to reduce the memory requested, `scontrol update` will probably work. If you want to increase the memory requested, ask your SysAdmin. Another option is to cancel the jobs and re-send them with the updated parameters. In any case, you should ask for the memory that you need, not much more.